# How to setup Sendgrid Inbound Parse and ActionMailbox

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sendgrid

I am trying to add Sendgrid inbound parse with ActionMailbox and rails 6. The problem I am having is how can I check if rails is receiving the emails from sendgrid. I have confirmed that Sendgrid receives the e-mails sent from my account, but they do not route it to my mailbox.

please explain how to setup the URL for rails

```
https://actionmailbox:PASSWORD@example.com/rails/action_mailbox/sendgrid/inbound_emails
```

I have added my password in rails credentials:edit under action_mailbox.ingress_password as this:

```
action_mailbox:
   ingress_password: MY_PASSWORD_HERE
```

I have also added the master.key to Heroku so it can read the credentials
And set ActionMailbox to use sendgrid as ingress in production.rb

```
config.action_mailbox.ingress = :sendgrid
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out: You have to add the password as HTTP "friendly" and paste it in where it says PASSWORD.

https://www.urlencoder.org/

Comment: I'm running into this same issue; what did you mean by HTTP friendly?